# Strategy for integrating multiple APIs for multi-tenant application

Tags: api, integration, multi-tenant

Can anyone suggest best way for implementing the below scenario.

In a multitenant application where we are tied up with different vendors, based on the logged in user we need to dynamically connect to a vendor's API and fetch user information.
What is the best way to design the scenario so that in future if we tie up with a new vendor we need to make minimum changes to our code to call his APIs. What are the pitfalls to be considered in such scenarios. Any pointers to any existing pattern/practice for such implementation would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a flexible approach.

Each new vendor will be registered in a vendors table

1. Create a mapping for each tenant to the list of accessible vendors in a table
2. For each vendor, create a configuration setting in a table which gives the keys or other details required to connect to the vendor by the tenant
3. On login, we identify the tenant. Then we access the vendors that the tenant can use.
4. Once identified, we can pickup the setting for this tenant to connect to that vendor
5. We will be able to connect
6. On onboarding a new vendor, register the vendor in the application and store the data in the vendor table
7. The SaaS admin can then provision the stored vendor for a tenant and provide the custom tenant connection parameters if required
8. From this point onwards, the tenant can then consume the features of the vendor API from the application.

This approach uses database tables which *will* require suitable encryption mechanisms to be employed to protect the secure data at rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saravanan. Any pattern which can be suitable in application code? I was thinking of Adapter pattern or dependency injection.

Comment: couple of patterns will be used internally like `DependencyInjection` for resolving the `TenantVendorsService`, `VendorsService` etc. `FactoryPattern` can be used for the tenant specific vendors API invocation